# ASP.NET C# - Sending Email from Gmail/Yahoo Live SMTP Server not working

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, gmail

I am struggling with attempting to send email from a .NET application.

I have tried everything from making a new account both gmail and yahoo (changed the host for yahoo), as well as, changing the port using and not using mail.To, allowing less secure apps, i also tried enabling 2 step verification and giving an application password for gmail all of which have failed with the same caught error of: {"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Authentication required"}

This is my code:

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "pw");
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        mail.Body = txtBody.Text;
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mail != null)
            {
                mail.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Solution: as people may have the problem in the future the solution was to remove the line of code: smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Comment: Never do `throw ex;` on a caught exception. Just use `throw;` so you preserve your stacktrace.

Comment: Should i change Exception ex to just exception then as well?

Comment: Hi.. tra this... Opel the browser and Gmail in the server where you execute it.. qnd then you have to set the security option of chrome to allow it be accessed and user from esternal

Comment: No, you should remove your try/catch completely. Only catch exceptions if you're planning on dealing with them right there. It doesn't make sense to simply catch and throw it again. If you want to make sure `mail` gets disposed, wrap it in a using statement.

Comment: This might help https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol

Comment: Thank you for the tips and help guys, i've removed the try/catch completely. I got it working now by removing smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;            
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "pw");
smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
```

Use those lines in such order.

Comment: Doing this has made a difference in a way. rather than the first error, i now get error: Failed to send mail

Comment: Wow you fixed it, well i bit of a mistake i remove smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false; and now it works. Thanks :)